# Aborting queries in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does snowflake incur charges when I abort long running queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because you pay for every second the warehouse is/was running (after the first 60 seconds which you get billed for just for starting the warehouse).

You also get billed if the long running query hits the execution timeout limit (default is something like 4 hours) you pay for those minutes, and you still have no answer.

But if you had the warehouse running many queries, and you run yet another query and then after time abort the new query, the warehouse was running so the new query itself will not be charged. But at the same time, the other queries run fractionally slow.

Comment: The default of 4 hours is the default session timeout. The default statement timeout is 2 days. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#statement-timeout-in-seconds Even though the session will time out first, the abort_detached_query defaults to false, so using default settings a session will time out in 4 hours and the query will continue running for up to 2 days. Every customer should change this timeout on every warehouse to what makes sense for the workload on the warehouse.

Comment: Also, should add that Snowflake has resource monitors that can be configured to provide alerts for behavior that exceeds expectations with respect to CPU consumption.

Comment: Ah, very interesting points, we had those "all set" to avoid surprise bills, but all those points aside, you are still billed for every second the warehouse is running, for which ever reason the warehouse is running.

Comment: Got it...Thanks for your valuable information!!

Answer (score 0):

CPU is charged by the Virtual Warehouse being up and running, not by individual query.  If you abort a query, and suspend the VWH you’re only charged during the time the VWH was in a running state.